# Nautilus crashing because of Dropbox (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: nautilus, dropbox, segmentation-fault

I have a strange problem that causes Nautilus to crash:
When Dropbox is active and I click (even just once) on the Dropbox folder in my Home folder Nautilus crashes. When I turn it on again it shows me hidden files and still crushes if I try to open the Dropbox folder again.
Everything works just fine when the Dropbox client is not running.

When running Nautilus from the shell and trying to access the Dropbox folder, I get the following error:

```
$ nautilus
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 1.6.0
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.


(nautilus:3835): Gtk-WARNING **: Refusing to add non-unique action 'NautilusDropbox::browse' to action group 'DirExtensionsMenuGroup'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What may cause this and how should I deal with this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem briefly. I need to force nautilus to quit...

```
 $ nautilus -q
```

so that dropbox could finished installing and then start it again manually by clicking on the folder icon on the side panel.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem in two ways:

1. Download and install the [32bit package](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/ubuntu/dropbox_1.6.0_i386.deb) of Dropbox (I had the problem with the 64bit version).
2. Download and use a newer beta version ([here](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/u/17/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-2.2.9.tar.gz) is the last stable one)

Hope it helps!